# Errors when trying ubuntu-drivers autoinstall ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, acer

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-55 with Nvidia Geoforce GTX which worked fine for about 3 months. Yesterday I shut it off; when I powered up again, the second monitor is not recognized. Tried several ideas with no luck, so finally reinstalled the whole thing... After a few tries, I finally got the second display to be recognized by using the X.org driver.

Now when I try to move the display side in settings-Displays, after clicking on Apply, my laptop goes to the start login screen and nothing is changed. I tried to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and see:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
        greet()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
        return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
        rv = self.invoke(ctx)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
        return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
        return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
        return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
        return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
        return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 432, in autoinstall
        command_install(config)
      File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
        UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in 
        nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
        with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

I installed from the same live USB stick I did originally AND updated the system a couple times (With Software updater and with console). Acer's support have not been helpful.

Comment: The problem is the package name with "-open" (either the 515-open or 520-open).  The packages without the "-open" should still work without editing a system script to make the "-open" versions work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a temporary fix until it's officially decided:
(taken from here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-1-nvidia-driver-open-kernel-nvidia-driver-515-open-issue/231356)

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py
```

at line 835 change

```
version = int(package_name.split('-')[-1])
```

to this

```
version = int(package_name.split('-')[2])
```